# Can I skip a word using multi cursors in VSCode with Vim KeyBinding?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

The operation performed in the captured video is to use VSCode's multi-cursor to select multiple identical words.
In detail, there are two operations: Ctrl+d to select, Ctrl+k and Ctrl+d to deselect.
My question is whether this operation can be done in VSCode with Vim KeyBinding (extension (vscodevim)).

[image]